# C# combine XML latest node only

Tags: c#, xml

I've got two XML files, OriginalXML and UpdatesXML that I need to combine and retain only the latest changes. My users essentially get a copy of the OriginalXML, make edits then submit the updates to a web service. I need to only update the OriginalXML with nodes that are newer in the UpdatesXML.

I can iterate over the nodes in the UpdatesXML, do a search of the OriginalXML for a match, check the timestamp and replace it if the updates is newer: (something like)

```
var OriginalXML = XDocument.Load("Original.xml");
var UpdatesXML = XDocument.Load("Updates.xml");

foreach (XElement WigitNode in UpdatesXML.Descendants("Wigit"))
{
    //Find the corresponding OriginalXML node based on the Wigit/Subnode1/Id attribute
    //Replace Original/Wigit with Updates/Wigit if Updates/Wigit/Editstamp/Timestamp attribute is later in Updates than Original
}
```

This whole thing seems rather clunky to me, especially if the Updates.xml has a lot of nodes. My use case is probably dozens at a time, so it may not be an issue, but it seems inefficient. Is there a straightforward XPath or xslt transform or something that would be faster or more efficient?

My XML looks like this:
Original.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="timmy" Timestamp="2013-09-13T20:22:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="A" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="phil" Timestamp="2013-09-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="B" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="biff" Timestamp="2013-10-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="C" />
  </Wigit>
</Root>
```

Updates.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="frank" Timestamp="2013-10-13T22:00:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="A" />
  </Wigit>
</Root>
```

And the desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="frank" Timestamp="2013-10-13T22:00:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="A" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="phil" Timestamp="2013-09-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="B" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="biff" Timestamp="2013-10-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="C" />
  </Wigit>
</Root>
```

**UPDATE: 10-15-2013**

I did some fiddling using Abhijeet Patel's code below and came up with this:

```
var query = from o in docOriginal.Element("Root").Elements("Wigit")
            from u in docUpdate.Element("Root").Elements("Wigit")
            let x = docUpdate.Element("Root")
                                .Elements("Wigit")
                                .SingleOrDefault(e => (e.Element("Subnode1").Attribute("id").Value ==     o.Element("Subnode1").Attribute("id").Value &&
                                                        DateTime.Parse(e.Element("EditStamp").Attribute("Timestamp").Value).Ticks > DateTime.Parse(o.Element("EditStamp").Attribute("Timestamp").Value).Ticks)) ?? o
            select x;
XDocument merged = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", query));
return merged;
```

This gives the proper result except that every node is duplicated:

```
<Root>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="frank" Timestamp="2013-10-13T22:00:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="SomeNewThing" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="frank" Timestamp="2013-10-13T22:00:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="SomeNewThing" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="phil" Timestamp="2013-09-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="B" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="phil" Timestamp="2013-09-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="B" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="biff" Timestamp="2013-10-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="C" />
  </Wigit>
  <Wigit>
    <EditStamp UserId="biff" Timestamp="2013-10-13T21:51:00" />
    <Subnode1 Id="C" />
  </Wigit>
</Root>
```

Any hints on how to not duplicate the results?

**Update 10-16-2013:**

The reason I was getting duplicate results is because the Updates doc I was using had two  nodes. The code needs to handle multiple changes at once, updating only the nodes with a greater timestamp.

```
string update = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Root>
    <Wigit id='A'>
    <EditStamp UserId='frank' Timestamp='2013-10-13T22:00:00' />
    <Subnode1 Id='SomeNewThing' />
    </Wigit>
    <Wigit id='B'>
    <EditStamp UserId='yomamma' Timestamp='2013-09-10T21:51:00' />
    <Subnode1 Id='B' />
    </Wigit>
</Root>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
            string original = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                            <Root>
                                <Wigit>
                                    <EditStamp UserId='timmy' Timestamp='2013-09-13T20:22:00' />
                                    <Subnode1 Id='A' />
                                </Wigit>
                                <Wigit>
                                    <EditStamp UserId='phil' Timestamp='2013-09-13T21:51:00' />
                                    <Subnode1 Id='B' />
                                </Wigit>
                                <Wigit>
                                    <EditStamp UserId='biff' Timestamp='2013-10-13T21:51:00' />
                                    <Subnode1 Id='C' />
                                </Wigit>
                            </Root>";

        string update = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                        <Root>
                            <Wigit>
                                <EditStamp UserId='frank' Timestamp='2010-10-13T22:00:00' />
                                <Subnode1 Id='A' />
                            </Wigit>
                            <Wigit id='B'>
                                <EditStamp UserId='yomamma' Timestamp='2013-09-09T21:51:00' />
                                <Subnode1 Id='B' />
                           </Wigit>
                    </Root>";

        XDocument docOriginal = XDocument.Parse(original);
        XDocument docUpdate = XDocument.Parse(update);

        var query = from o in docOriginal.Element("Root").Elements("Wigit")
                    let x = docUpdate.Element("Root")
                                     .Elements("Wigit")
                                     .SingleOrDefault(e =>
                                        e.Element("Subnode1").Attribute("Id").Value == o.Element("Subnode1").Attribute("Id").Value
                                        && (DateTime.Parse(e.Element("EditStamp").Attribute("Timestamp").Value) > DateTime.Parse(o.Element("EditStamp").Attribute("Timestamp").Value))
                                     ) ?? o
                    select x;
        XDocument merged = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", query));
        Console.WriteLine(merged.ToString());
```

Comment: That's really really close to what I need (and awesomely straightforward!) One small problem is the result of that query has every <wigit> node in it's own <root> node. `<Root>
  <Root>
    <Wigit>
      <EditStamp UserId="frank" Timestamp="2013-10-13T22:00:00" />
      <Subnode1 Id="A" />
    </Wigit>
  </Root>
  <Root>
    <Wigit>
      <EditStamp UserId="phil" Timestamp="2013-09-13T21:51:00" />
      <Subnode1 Id="B" />
    </Wigit>
  </Root>
  <Root>
    ...
  </Root>
</Root>`

Comment: Oversight on my part during debugging.I updated the answer.Basically the select in the Linq query needed to do a 'select x' Try it now :-)

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It occurs to me I completely don't understand your code :-P. How does it utilize the timestamp to determine whether the node should be updated?

Comment: I made an update to the original question with an update I tried to your code to look at the timestamp and the results I get back. Can you help me out?

Comment: I updated the answer to use both the SubNodeId  and the TimeStamp.This should do the trick

Comment: Ok, I figured out what is going on in my code. My update doc has two <Wigit> nodes which is why it is duplicating my results. I've made one last update to my question. Can you help me out one last time?

Comment: @nick: Sure. I updated the answer. Try it out. Basically the inner "from" is not really required since it would perform a cross join(Cartesian product) and hence the duplicate nodes. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: I really wish I could buy you a beer. A check mark as answered and a plus one just isn't enough thanks for the help you've given me. Thanks a million!